# How to show or hide a social sharing buttons div on mouseover using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I am trying to work out how to show hidden shearing (facebook, google+, twitter) divs when hovering over one div.

Take this as an example animation of sharing round div on top right side  : http://www.gethyapp.com/

please see what i have done : http://goo.gl/6XDM8
here is what I have done in code:

HTML

```
<div class="share">share
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="facebook">fb</div>
    <div class="google-plus">g+</div>
    <div class="twitter">t</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.share{
    background-color: #DA251D;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.share .facebook,
.share .google-plus,
.share .twitter,
.share .line {
    display:none;
}
.facebook{
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;

}
.google-plus{
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;

}
.twitter{
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;

}
.line{
    width: 1px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
}
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $(".share").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".line").delay(50).fadeIn().animate({width: 1, height: 200, opacity: 1, top:10},200);
        $(this).find(".facebook").delay(100).fadeIn().animate({width: 32, height: 32, opacity: 1},400);
        $(this).find(".google-plus").delay(300).fadeIn().animate({width: 32, height: 32, opacity: 1},400);
        $(this).find(".twitter").delay(500).fadeIn().animate({width: 32, height: 32, opacity: 1},400);
    }, function(){
          $(this).find(".line").delay(50).fadeIn().animate({width: 1, height: 0, opacity: 0, top:-10},200)
          $(this).find(".facebook").delay(500).animate({width: 0, height: 0, opacity: 0},400);
          $(this).find(".google-plus").delay(300).animate({width: 0, height: 0, opacity: 0},400);
          $(this).find(".twitter").delay(100).animate({width: 0, height: 0, opacity: 0},400);
    });
});
```

How can I make it so when you hover over the share box  another shearing box appears next to it?

Comment: can you explain more? what your problem is?

Comment: Your Fiddle seems to work, except some small CSS problems maybe... What do you exactly want to do ?

Comment: add a function the the on hover event and add the divs that are hidden on page load.

Comment: You're using opacity, use display instead.

Comment: i wanted to make exactly sharing animation button like this http://www.gethyapp.com/ website have on right side top.

Comment: i'm not expert on jquery. please can any one help me to make share animation like http://www.gethyapp.com website...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I visited the site you mentioned. With reference to that site i have taken the code for doing this animation as

```
 <style type="text/css">
    #share
    {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        right: 65px;
        top: 20px;
        line-height: 46px;
        padding-right: 59px;
    }
    #share .list
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: transparent;
    }
    #share .list strong, #share .list a
    {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 46px;
        height: 46px;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-border-radius: 23px;
        -moz-border-radius: 23px;
        border-radius: 23px;
        background: #fff;
        color: #3fbad8;
        margin: 0 0 6px;
        font-family: 'icomoon';
    }
    #share .list strong
    {
        cursor: default;
    }
    .ie9 #share .list strong
    {
        padding-top: 5px;
        height: 41px;
    }
    #share .list strong span
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 1px;
        height: 0;
        background: #fff;
        -webkit-transition: height .0001s linear;
        -moz-transition: height .0001s linear;
        -ms-transition: height .0001s linear;
        -o-transition: height .0001s linear;
        transition: height .0001s linear;
        opacity: 0;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
    }
    #share .list a
    {
        background: #ff3;
        color: #000;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .0001s linear, background .0001s ease, color .0001s ease;
        -moz-transition: -moz-transform .0001s linear, background .0001s ease, color .0001s ease;
        -ms-transition: -ms-transform .0001s linear, background .0001s ease, color .0001s ease;
        -o-transition: -o-transform .0001s linear, background .0001s ease, color .0001s ease;
        transition: transform .0001s linear,background .0001s ease,color .0001s ease;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0) translate3d(0,0,0);
        -moz-transform: scale(0) translate3d(0,0,0);
        -ms-transform: scale(0) translate3d(0,0,0);
        -o-transform: scale(0) translate3d(0,0,0);
        transform: scale(0) translate3d(0,0,0);
        opacity: 0;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
    }
    #share .list a:hover
    {
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #share .list .tw
    {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    #share .list .fb
    {
        font-size: 32px;
    }
    #share .list .gp
    {
        font-size: 32px;
    }
    #share .list:hover strong span, #share .list.hover strong span
    {
        height: 135px;
        opacity: 1;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
        -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
        -moz-transition-duration: .3s;
        -ms-transition-duration: .3s;
        -o-transition-duration: .3s;
        transition-duration: .3s;
    }
    #share .list:hover a, #share .list.hover a
    {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate3d(0,0,0);
        -moz-transform: scale(1) translate3d(0,0,0);
        -ms-transform: scale(1) translate3d(0,0,0);
        -o-transform: scale(1) translate3d(0,0,0);
        transform: scale(1) translate3d(0,0,0);
        opacity: 1;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
        -webkit-transition-duration: .3s,.4s,.4s;
        -moz-transition-duration: .3s,.4s,.4s;
        -ms-transition-duration: .3s,.4s,.4s;
        -o-transition-duration: .3s,.4s,.4s;
        transition-duration: .3s,.4s,.4s;
    }
    #share .list:hover .tw, #share .list.hover .tw
    {
        -webkit-transition-delay: .1s,.0001s,.0001s;
        -moz-transition-delay: .1s,.0001s,.0001s;
        -ms-transition-delay: .1s,.0001s,.0001s;
        -o-transition-delay: .1s,.0001s,.0001s;
        transition-delay: .1s,.0001s,.0001s;
    }
    #share .list:hover .fb, #share .list.hover .fb
    {
        -webkit-transition-delay: .2s,.0001s,.0001s;
        -moz-transition-delay: .2s,.0001s,.0001s;
        -ms-transition-delay: .2s,.0001s,.0001s;
        -o-transition-delay: .2s,.0001s,.0001s;
        transition-delay: .2s,.0001s,.0001s;
    }
    #share .list:hover .gp, #share .list.hover .gp
    {
        -webkit-transition-delay: .3s,.0001s,.0001s;
        -moz-transition-delay: .3s,.0001s,.0001s;
        -ms-transition-delay: .3s,.0001s,.0001s;
        -o-transition-delay: .3s,.0001s,.0001s;
        transition-delay: .3s,.0001s,.0001s;
    }
</style>

<p id="share" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
    Want Solution <span class="list"><strong>?? <span></span>
    </strong><a class="tw">twr</a> <a class="fb">fb</a> <a class="gp">G+</a> </span>
</p>
```

This is exactly the same animation as in the site except the logo of the brand/Site.
Same code as in the link.

Please have a look once and hope help this is what you want.

Thanks 
Prashant

Comment: Hi Prashant, thanks for your instant support. thank you very much for this solution, exactly the same animation i want. one more thing i want in this animation, when mouse hover all share div animate an show but when mouse out i want also same animation like IN and OUT. can we do that ?? and also one more things mouse hover animation is not working on Opera Browser, can we fix it, or can we do this animation through jquery so that animation will work in all browsers... please suggest me, and once again thanks for your help :)